# How to move artifacts in artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

Can someone help me find a way to copy an artifact from one artifactory location to another location, inside the same repository. I understand there are ways to move artifactory between repositories, but my requirement is to move **`x1`** to **`module-2`** as in below folder structure.

```
+
+- repository
   +- com
      +- module-1
      |  +- x1
      +- module-2
         +- x2
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Fwiw, I just did it using the admin console, which has "copy" and "move" buttons that also work across repos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is using the [REST API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem). Here's an example:

```
curl -v -X -d "" POST -uusername "http://host:port/artifactory/api/move/repository/com/module-1/x1?to=/repository/com/module2/x1"
```

Comment: I dint try this (not brave enough). Thank you anyway :)

Comment: There are `dryRun` and `failFast` flags for the less brave among us :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-MovingFiles). The usage is something like

```sh
jfrog rt move repository/com/module-1/x1 repository/com/module2/x1
```

The cli is especially useful when you want to move multiple files.